# sklearn-KNearestNeighbors with Multilabels

Tags: scikit-learn, knn, multilabel-classification

I have a dataset with features and their labels.

it looks like this:

```
X1, X2, X3, X4, X5 .. Xn L1, L2, L3
Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5 .. Yn L5, L2
..
```

I want to train a KNeighborsClassifier on this dataset. It seems like sklearn does not take multilabels. I have been trying this:

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
Y = mlb.fit_transform(Y)

# parameters:  n_neighbors=[5,15], weights = 'uniform', 'distance'
bagging = BaggingClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors =5,weights ='uniform'), max_samples = 0.6, max_features= 0.7, verbose =1, oob_score =True)
scores = cross_val_score(bagging, X, Y, verbose =1, cv=3, n_jobs=3, scoring='f1_macro')
```

It is giving me `ValueError: bad input shape`

Is there a way that I can run multilabel classifier in sklearn?

Comment: `KNeighborsClassifier` does take multi-labels, not `BaggingClassifier` does not. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4758

Answer (score 2):

According to sklearn [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) the classifiers that support multioutput-multiclass classification tasks are:

> Decision Trees, Random Forests, Nearest Neighbors

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a binary matrix for your labels, you can use `OneVsRestClassifier` to make your `BaggingClassifier` handle multilabel predictions. Code should now look like:

```
bagging = BaggingClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, weights='uniform'), max_samples=0.6, max_features=0.7, verbose=1, oob_score=True)
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(bagging)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, Y, verbose=1, cv=3, n_jobs=3, scoring='f1_macro')
```

You can use the `OneVsRestClassifier` with any of the sklearn models to do multilabel classification.

Here's an explanation:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#one-vs-the-rest

And here are the docs:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html

Answer (score 2):

For anybody who finds this looking for multi-label KNN (MLKNN) options, I would recommend using skmultilearn, which is built on top of sklearn, so easy to use if you are familiar with the latter package.

Documentation [here](http://scikit.ml/api/skmultilearn.adapt.mlknn.html). This example is from the documentation:

```
from skmultilearn.adapt import MLkNN

classifier = MLkNN(k=3)

# train
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# predict
predictions = classifier.predict(X_test)
```